# Need Multi Site Docs/Instruction for Joomla

Tags: joomla, multisite

I've read wiki multi-site instructions which mentions Drupal and Wordpress CMS. Can someone point me to Joomla instructions with steps that allows for configuring the CiviCRM (4.7.4) component to points to different domain than existing Joomla (Joomla! 3.5.0 Stable) site. i.e. website = redcandy.com while civiCRM = yellowcandy.com.

Comment: After further reading, I realized a Joomla multi-domain solution is what I was seeking.  Eventually, found virtual domain Joomla extension @ http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains which, at the moment, appears to satisfy multi-domain configuration needs.